# QComboBox->addItems() crashed application when using findChild()

Tags: qt, crash, qcombobox

I have a question regarding using the `findChild()` function.

For instance, I have 2 slots:

```
QComboBox *comboBoxType;
QComboBox *comboBoxName;

void MainWindow::on_Start_clicked()
{
    ui->stackedWidget->setCurrentIndex(1);
    
    comboBoxType = ui->stackedWidget->findChild<QComboBox *>("typeComboBox", Qt::FindChildrenRecursively);
    comboBoxType->addItem("Hash");
    comboBoxType->addItem("Translate");

    comboBoxName = ui->stackedWidget->findChild<QComboBox *>("nameComboBox", Qt::FindChildrenRecursively);
}

void MainWindow::on_typeComboBox_currentTextChanged(const QString &arg1)
{
    comboBoxName->addItem("MD5");
}
```

**Explaination**:

When `StartButton` is clicked, `on_Start_clicked()` is triggered, `setCurrentIndex()` is called to switch the widget and `findChild()` is called to find a `QComboBox` named `nameComboBox`.

Right after that `on_typeComboBox_currentTextChanged()` is triggered and add an item to that `QComboBox`.

It should be noted that the 2 `QComboBox` is located inside the widget which was switched to at the start, and both signals (`clicked()` and `currentTextChanged()`) is activated (almost) together, or just very close.

But the application crashed:

```
11:06:08: The program has unexpectedly finished.
11:06:08: The process was ended forcefully.
11:06:08: D:\...\build-cryptog-Desktop_Qt_5_15_2_MinGW_64_bit-Debug\debug\cryptog.exe crashed.
```

But, if I moved the `findChild()` function upward:

```
void MainWindow::on_Start_clicked()
{
    ui->stackedWidget->setCurrentIndex(1);

    comboBoxName = ui->stackedWidget->findChild<QComboBox *>("nameComboBox", Qt::FindChildrenRecursively);
    comboBoxType = ui->stackedWidget->findChild<QComboBox *>("typeComboBox", Qt::FindChildrenRecursively);
    comboBoxType->addItem("Hash");
    comboBoxType->addItem("Translate");
}
```

The program ran fine.

What seems to be the problem here? I suspected that is because the `addItem()` command somehow is ran **before** `findChild()` could located the `QComboBox`, but I might be wrong here.

Comment: Maybe the child was not found. You don't check if the pointer returned is null. You also don't appear to initialize the `comboBoxType` and `comboBoxName` variables. So if `on_typeComboBox_currentTextChanged` was called before `on_Start_clicked()` you also have undefined behavior.

Comment: @drescherjm so how could I initialize those variables? So that at least it'd tell me the error instead of just crashing?

Comment: `QComboBox *comboBoxType{}; QComboBox *comboBoxName{};`

Comment: `if (comboBoxName)  {comboBoxName->addItem("MD5"); } else { qDebug() << "comboBoxName is not initialized!"; }`